# FacebookCallback not being executed

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have an app in which I implemented facebook login which was working last time I checked. For some reason, now, after I click the button nothing happens.

My `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
```

my `loginButton`

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    loginButton.setFragment(this);

    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
```

my `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("askj","Callback called with requestCode "+requestCode+" + resultCode "+resultCode);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

my `mFacebookCallback`

```
 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("askj", "onSuccess");
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.d("askj", "profile " + profile.toString());
        if (profile != null) {
            Intent upanel = new Intent(getActivity(), AfterLogin.class);
            upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(upanel);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("askj", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("askj", "onError " + e);
    }
};
```

This is what is being printed in logCat once the button is clicked:

```
Callback called with requestCode 129742 + resultCode -1
```

I don't get anything from `mFacebookCallback` in the console.

Edit: How can I add a specific requestCode to this callback ?

Edit2: For anyone having this problem, I solved it by removing `loginButton.setFragment(this);`. I still have this question though `How can I add a specific requestCode to this callback ?`

Comment: could you manage to find how to give specific request code. Due to the mismatching request code, my call backs are too not called. It's been two days. I learnt so much but could not resolve. Any help ?